# Find the tens place of a number

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

For any odd number N ending with the digits $1,3,7$ or $9$, $(N)^{20\cdot n}$ ends with $01$. Here, $n$ is any natural number

Now I have tested the result with a few odd numbers. But is there any easy proof of this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Carmichael function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(100)=20,a^{20}\equiv1\pmod{100}$ for $(a,100)=1$

Then $a^{20n}=(a^{20})^n\equiv1^n\pmod{100}$ for any natural number $n$

Any number ending with $1,3,7,9$ is relatively prime with $10,$ hence with $100$

Comment: What is lambda?

Comment: @archangel89, Link supplied for  Carmichael function

Comment: Can you give me additional insight on how to calculate lambda(n). I guess it can be calculated through totient function and there is also a general L.C.M rule. But is the totient(n)  of any primes or power of primes=lambda(n). If not then how to calculate lambda(n) for 100?

Comment: @archangel89, Apart from the link in the answer, see also: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Carmichael_function and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html

Comment: If lambda is defined as the smallest integer having this property then, why $54571^{10}=1(mod 100)$? It should be 20 right?, because lambda(100)=20.

Comment: @archangel89, Please read the definition(s). It the smallest exponent such that $a^{\lambda(n)}\equiv1\pmod n$ for all $a,(a,n)=1$

Comment: Sorry for asking again. But shouldn't the min required exponent of 54571 be 20 rather than 10 to get a remainder of 1. I don't quite understand. Because as per the definition it should be the lowest exponent possible and lambda(100)=20, not 10. Still we get a remainder 01.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20112/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-archangel89).

Comment: Please look into chat transcript